# Plot a dataframe in scala using WISP

Tags: scala, apache-spark, plot

I need to plot my dataframe using WISP. I am using Apache Sprak in Scala. However it seems that it can not accept a dataframe.

```
+-----+--------------------+------------------+
|label|            features|        prediction|
+-----+--------------------+------------------+
|  101|[1.497846976E9,10...|101.22752534884378|
|  101|[1.497846976E9,10...|101.22752534884378|
|  101|[1.497846976E9,10...|101.22752534884378|
|  101|[1.497846976E9,10...|101.22752534884378|
|  101|[1.497846976E9,10...|101.22752534884378|
+-----+--------------------+------------------+
```

I also tried to change my datarame to Seq using the following code but, it does't work.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{collect_list, collect_set}
val label=predictions.groupBy($"label").agg(collect_list($"label").alias("label"))
val predicted=  predictions.groupBy($"prediction").agg(collect_list($"prediction").alias("prediction"))

line(predicted)
```

It shows me the following error:

```
Error:(157, 10) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: com.quantifind.charts.repl.IterablePair[?,?,?,?]
    line(predicted)
```

Is there any trick to plot a dataframe like below using WISP? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:

According to answer number one, As I try to install vegas libraries, I got an error:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[warn] ==== MapR Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repository.mapr.com/maven/com/github/aishfenton/vegas-spark_2.10_2.11/0.2.0/vegas-spark_2.10_2.11-0.2.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.aishfenton#vegas-spark_2.10_2.11;0.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.github.aishfenton:vegas-spark_2.10_2.11:0.2.0 (/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/ML_Alpha/build.sbt#L15-34)
[warn]        +- ml:ml_2.11:1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.aishfenton#vegas-spark_2.10_2.11;0.2.0: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.aishfenton#vegas-spark_2.10_2.11;0.2.0: not found
[error] Total time: 27 s, completed Sep 22, 2017 1:06:23 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="file:/Users/saeedtkh/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea2017.1/sbt.last.log">file:/Users/saeedtkh/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea2017.1/sbt.last.log</a>
```

My bulid.sbt file is:

```
name := "ML"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

retrieveManaged := true

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "MapR Repository" at "http://repository.mapr.com/maven/"



libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

  "co.theasi" %% "plotly" % "0.2.0",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-csv" % "1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.0.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.0.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.0.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.0.2",
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze" % "0.11.2",
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze-natives" % "0.11.2",
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze-viz" % "0.11.2",
  "com.quantifind" %% "wisp" % "0.0.4"
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.aishfenton/vegas-spark_2.10
  //"com.github.aishfenton" %% "vegas-spark_2.10" % "0.2.0"

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to plot? Have you tried using Vegas? [Vegas plotting library for Scala](https://github.com/vegas-viz/Vegas)

An example for getting histograms of a dataframe column:

Add the following lines to your build file.

```
"org.vegas-viz" %% "vegas" % "0.3.9",
"org.vegas-viz" %% "vegas-spark" % "0.3.9"
```

An example code

```
import vegas._
import vegas.render.WindowRenderer._
import vegas.sparkExt._

val plot = Vegas("approval date").
           withDataFrame(castedDf).
           mark(Bar).
           encodeX("columnName", Quant, bin=Bin(maxbins=20.0), sortOrder=SortOrder.Desc).
           show
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying, I wanted to compare the prediction and label (The real value for prediction) over a graph.

Comment: The only problem is that, I can not add its library on my inteliJ idea. I think because my scala version is 2.8.11. I have added my build.sbt content to the question. Thanks.

Comment: I see.I am not very familiar with the wisp framework. But Vegas allows you to make scatter plots between two variables. In this case, it will be predictions and labels. I have added the dependency information in my previous code. Hope it helps.